# Exception in Tkinter Callback (Using Python Turtle)

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-3.7

I am making a text-based lunar landing simulation in turtle. When the player presses the space bar to go to the actual interface of the simulation, everything works fine. After I click on the screen to exit the program (this is a work in progress and am really just testing things out as I create them) I get this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "E:\Python\Python37-32\lib\turtle.py", line 701, in eventfun
    fun()
  File "E:\Projects\Turtle\Simulations\Lunar Landing Simulation\lunarLandingSim.py", line 54, in start
    playSim()
  File "E:\Projects\Turtle\Simulations\Lunar Landing Simulation\lunarLandingSim.py", line 103, in playSim
    wn.bgcolor("black")
  File "E:\Python\Python37-32\lib\turtle.py", line 1237, in bgcolor
    color = self._colorstr(args)
  File "E:\Python\Python37-32\lib\turtle.py", line 1158, in _colorstr
    raise TurtleGraphicsError("bad color string: %s" % str(color))
turtle.TurtleGraphicsError: bad color string: black
```

This here is my code:

```
import turtle
import random
import time


delay = 0.1
start = False

##### Use turtle.setheading(0) and turtle.heading() for directional calcualtion

# Lander Variables/Data
vertVel = 0
latVel = 0

fuel = 0

craftMass = 0
fuelMass = 0

craftWeight = craftMass * 0
fuelWeight = fuelMass * 0


# Screen setup
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.setup(width = 600, height = 600)
wn.title("Lunar Lander")
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.tracer(0)

# Startup/Intro
greet = turtle.Turtle()
greet.hideturtle()
greet.goto(-235, 250)
greet.color("white")
greet.write("Welcome to Lunar Landing Sim!", font = ("Arial", 25, "normal"))
greet.goto(-175, 175)
greet.write("""The goal is to land on the Lunar surface
below five meters per second.""", font = ("Arial", 15, "normal"))
greet.goto(-175, 0)
greet.write("""Controls:
            Engage engine: Up Key
            Rotate left: Left Key
            Rotate right: Right Key
            Increase throttle: Shift Key
            Decrease throttle: Ctrl key
            """, font = ("Arial", 15, "normal"))
greet.goto(-235, -25)
greet.write("Press the Space Bar to begin.", font = ("Arial", 25, "normal"))


def start():
    wn.clear()
    playSim()

def thrust():
    placeholder = None
    print("Thrust")

def left():
  placeholder = None
  print("Left")

def right():
  placeholder = None
  print("Right")

def shift():
    placeholder = None
    print("Shift")

def ctrl():
    placeholder = None
    print("Control")


wn.onkeypress(start, "space")
wn.onkeypress(thrust, "Up")
wn.onkeypress(left, "Left")
wn.onkeypress(right, "Right")
wn.onkeypress(shift, "Shift_L")
wn.onkeypress(ctrl, "Control_L")
wn.listen()


# Vertical Velocity
vV = turtle.Turtle()
vV.goto(-280, 250)
vV.hideturtle()
vV.color("white")


# Lateral Velocity
lV = turtle.Turtle()
lV.goto(-280, 210)
lV.hideturtle()
lV.color("white")



def playSim():
    while True:
        wn.bgcolor("black")


        # vV = vertical velocity
        vVDisplay = "Vertical velocity: " + str(vertVel)
        vV.write(vVDisplay, font = ("Arial", 25, "normal"))

        # lV = lateral velocity
        lVDisplay = "Lateral velocity: " + str(latVel)
        lV.write(lVDisplay, font = ("Arial", 25, "normal"))

        # Use wn.clear() for clearing the screen at the end of the loop

        wn.exitonclick()
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I am not sure why it is coming up with this error. Everything seems to be alright. Must be a tedious thing that I am not aware of.

Comment: Are you sure that black is a valid background color? Have you successfully created black backgrounds before? Try creating the simplest possible turtle program that has a black background, and see if that works.

Comment: Yes, I have. It doesn't make any sense as to why it would say it is invalid.

Comment: I don't know much about turtle, but here's my wild guess: you can only set the background color of the window while the window is open. Since `playSim` contains a while loop, `bgcolor` can execute after `exitonclick` has been called, and after the window is closed.

Comment: Thank you! I'll find out how I can get the loop to stop after the window has been closed to see if this is indeed the problem. This really helps :)

Comment: @Kevin Your observation is correct, that's why it was coming up with the error. Thank you so much . It's always those little logical mishaps and syntax errors that completely screw the program over. Again, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your code.  Along with the incorrectly placed `exitonclick()`, you've got a `while True:` which has no place in an event-driven world like turtle.

But you've also tripped a bug that's not of your making.  Even if you correctly place the `exitonclick()`, and replace the `while True:` with a timer event, clicking on the window won't end the simulation.  Here's why:

The `exitonclick()` basically calls the screen's `onclick()` method with a function that wraps `bye()`.  But when you call `clear()` on the screen in `start()`, it unsets all the `onclick()` settings for the screen.  Including the one set by `exitonclick()`!

Below is my skeletal rework of your code to address all of the above issues:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

BIG_FONT = ("Arial", 25, "normal")
SMALL_FONT = ("Arial", 15, "normal")

def start():
    screen.clear()
    screen.onclick(lambda x, y: screen.bye())

    vV.write(vVDisplay + str(vertVel), font=BIG_FONT)
    lV.write(lVDisplay + str(latVel), font=BIG_FONT)

    playSim()

def playSim():
    global vertVel, latVel

    screen.bgcolor("black")

    # vV = vertical velocity
    vV.undo()
    vV.write(vVDisplay + str(vertVel), font=BIG_FONT)

    # lV = lateral velocity
    lV.undo()
    lV.write(lVDisplay+ str(latVel), font=BIG_FONT)

    vertVel += 1
    latVel -= 1

    screen.ontimer(playSim, 1000)

# Lander Variables/Data
vertVel = 0
latVel = 0

# Screen setup
screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
screen.title("Lunar Lander")
screen.bgcolor("black")

# Startup/Intro
greet = Turtle(visible=False)
greet.color("white")
greet.penup()

greet.goto(-235, 250)
greet.write("Welcome to Lunar Landing Sim!", font=BIG_FONT)

greet.goto(-175, 175)
greet.write("""The goal is to land on the Lunar surface
below five meters per second.""", font=SMALL_FONT)

greet.goto(-175, 0)
greet.write("""Controls:
            Engage engine: Up Key
            Rotate left: Left Key
            Rotate right: Right Key
            Increase throttle: Shift Key
            Decrease throttle: Ctrl key
            """, font=SMALL_FONT)

greet.goto(-235, -25)
greet.write("Press the Space Bar to begin.", font=BIG_FONT)

# Vertical Velocity
vVDisplay = "Vertical velocity: "
vV = Turtle(visible=False)
vV.color("white")
vV.penup()
vV.goto(-280, 250)

# Lateral Velocity
lVDisplay = "Lateral velocity: "
lV = Turtle(visible=False)
lV.color("white")
lV.penup()
lV.goto(-280, 210)

screen.onkeypress(start, "space")

screen.listen()

screen.mainloop()
```